# Consulta directa en MySql

Tags: mysql, sql

Es solo una tabla (ciudades) y lo que necesito es obtener el name (columna nombre) y state_abbr (columna estado abreviado) filtrado por solo un estado (state_abbr) ejemplo

Tabla ciudades
_____________________________
**state_abbr** | **name**    | **zip**
TX               |  El Paso | xxxx
TX               |  El Paso | xxxx
TX               |  El Paso | xxxx
IL                 |  El Paso | xxxx
AR              |  El Paso | xxxx
IA                | Durango | xxxx
CO             | Durango | xxxx
CO             | Durango | xxxx

**El resultado que necesito es**:
_____________________________
**state_abbr** | **name**    | **zip**
TX               |  El Paso | xxxx
IL                 | El Paso | xxxx
AR              |  El Paso | xxxx
IA                | Durango | xxxx
CO             | Durango | xxxx

E intentado con:

```
select * from cities group by name order by name asc
```

Pero solo muestra un registro por cada nombre de ciudad
(Este resultado no quiero)
_____________________________
**state_abbr** | **name**    | **zip**
TX               |  El Paso | xxxx
AR              |  El Paso | xxxx
IA                | Durango | xxxx

Comment: select * from `cities` group by `name` order by `name` asc

Pero solo muestra un registro por cada nombre de ciudad

Comment: Con `SELECT DISTINCT`

Comment: podrias mostrar que queres como resultado?

Comment: Segun entiendo solo necesitas agregar `state_abbr ` an GROUP BY: `select * from cities group by state_abbr , name order by name asc`

Comment: @F.Igor tu respuesta fue la solución. muchas gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si solo agrupas por *name*, el estado es ignorado y aunque muestre el nombre, puede tener resultados impredecibles, porque puede mostrar el nombre de la estado de una ciudad o la otra.

Por ejemplo si la ciudad de El Paso está en dos estados diferentes, cuando muestres uno de los nombres ¿a qué estado pertenece?.

Por ello, primero agrupa por estado y dentro de las ciudades de cada estado agrupa por *state_abbr* para que te muestre información correcta.

```
select * from cities group by state_abbr, name order by name asc
```

Comment: Hola Omar, aunque esta respuesta parece servir para resolver el problema de la pregunta, ha sido marcad como de baja calidad por la comunidad debido a su extensión y contenido. Por favor, edítala para añadir algo más de información: ¿qué hace ese SELECT? ¿cómo resuelve el problema? ¿qué es diferente con el SELECT de la pregunta? Lee [answer] y visita el  [tour] para más información.

Comment: Gracias por los comentarios Alvaro, espero que se muestre mejor ahora :)